# Integral over two sets when the measure of their symetric difference equals zero

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two measurable sets of $X$. Show that if $m(S(A,B))=0 $ then $$\int_{A} f\, dm =\int_{B} f\,dm,$$ where $S(A, B)$ is the symetric difference.

my method was to prove that $\int_{A\backslash B} f = \int_{B\backslash A} f$ but I was not successful. Any help will be appreciated.

I should also add that f is nonnegativz and measurable.

Comment: you may consider to find out what is m(B\A) and m(A\B).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to combine the facts, $A\setminus B\subseteq S(A,B)$ and $A=(A\setminus B)\sqcup (A\cap B)$, where $\sqcup$ is disjoint union, to show
$$
\int_A f\, dm=\int_{A\cap B}f\, dm.
$$
Then do the same for $B$.

Comment: Thank you. Both integral over A\B and B\A are zero which implied the equaLity over A and B.